# How avoid redundant variable in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have 2 controllers.

The first one is listController.js:

```
app.controller('listCtrl', function($scope, $http, $controller, $window) {
     $scope.user = [{id:1,name:'rina'},{id:2,name:'anna'},{id:3,name:'yuna'}];
});
```

and the second is editController.js

```
app.controller('editCtrl', function($scope, $http, $controller, $window) {
    $scope.user = [{id:1,name:'rina'},{id:2,name:'anna'},{id:3,name:'yuna'}];
});
```

As u can see. I used the variable `$scope.user` in both controller. Now I want to used it once. I mean I want to avoid redundant codes. How can I call the variable in any of my controller. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a service, which will be responsible for providing the data.

```
app.service('UsersService', function() {
    this.getUsers = function() {
        return [{id:1,name:'rina'},{id:2,name:'anna'},{id:3,name:'yuna'}];
    }
});
```

then in your controllers you can put it like this:

```
app.controller('listCtrl', function($scope, $http, $controller, $window, UsersService) {
    $scope.user = UsersService.getUsers();
});
```